# MySQL Query not working in MySQLi but works in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm putting together an API for an iOS app and need to get locations nearby a geo coordinate.

I tried this query in mysqli and it returns no results. When I do it in a regular mysql_query it works perfectly. I also tested the query in phpmyadmin where it completes successfully as well.

```
SELECT id, name, address, city, state, longitude, latitude, ( $miles * acos( cos( radians($latitude) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians($longitude) ) + sin( radians($latitude) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
        FROM locations HAVING distance < $distance ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0, 20
```

This is the query with the variables filled in:

```
 SELECT id, name, address, city, state, longitude, latitude, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(40.735767) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-73.991806) ) + sin( radians(40.735767) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
        FROM locations HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0, 20
```

Is there something I'm missing why it will not work in `mysqli`?

This is the working mysql query code

```
 mysql_connect('localhost', 'test', 'test') or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db('testdb') or die(mysql_error()); 
 $locations = array();
 $miles = 3959;
 $distance = 25;
 $latitude = "40.735767";
 $longitude = "-73.991806";

 $data = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, address, city, state, longitude, latitude, ( $miles * acos( cos( radians($latitude) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians($longitude) ) + sin( radians($latitude) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
        FROM locations HAVING distance < $distance ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0, 20") 
   or die(mysql_error()); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
  array_push($locations, $row);
}
```

I'm using MysqliDb Class https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class so that should work as follows

```
      $row = $db->rawQuery("SELECT id, name, address, city, state, longitude, latitude, ( ? * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
        FROM locations HAVING distance < ? ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0, 20", array($miles, $latitude, $longitude, $latitude, $distance));

      if (count($row) > 0){
          // if found, return JSON response
          echo json_encode($row[0]);
      }
```

Even when I use the basic template I found for mysqli it fails.

```
$locations = array();
$miles = 3959;
$distance = 25;
$latitude = "40.735767";
$longitude = "-73.991806";

// Connect to database
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','test','test','testdb');

// Check for Errors
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Prepare Query
$query = "SELECT id, name, address, city, state, longitude, latitude, ( $miles * acos( cos( radians($latitude) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians($longitude) ) + sin( radians($latitude) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
        FROM locations HAVING distance < $distance ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0, 20";

// Escape Query
$query = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$query);

// Perform Query
if($result = mysqli_query($link,$query)){

 // Cycle through results
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
  array_push($locations, $row);
 }
 // Free Result Set
 mysqli_free_result($result);
}

// Close Connection
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Where are the calls to the mysql and mysqli functions?

Comment: Depends on "how" you're querying it. You're only showing us one line of code. Show us your full code.

Comment: Updated the code above based on above comments.

Comment: How is `$locations` being referenced?

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's an empty array created before the query is run.       `$locations = array();` I updated above to add the variables.

Comment: Are you trying to use `MysqliDb Class` with your new `mysqli_` version, by any chance?

Comment: I would like to have all queries go through MysqlDb class, but when it kept failing I was trying to figure out where the point of failure was by testing a bunch of different ways to query the database. I didn't know if the class was the issue or my query or my code for the query. Is this the information you are looking for mysqli_ version? `Server version: 50531 Client library version: mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026`

Comment: Best I can suggest is make an exact replica of what you already have by changing all instances of `mysql_` to `mysqli_` however, if you get error messages, keep track of them and then Google those error messages, while making sure you have some form of error reporting. `var_dump();` can also be your friend. Certain functionalities differ from `mysql_` to `mysqli_` yet you should be able to find the proper syntax usage. Sorry, that's the best I can tell you.

Comment: What are you doing? Escaping a complete query? That will lead to errors.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel that was one I tried as a quick test to see if it would work to try to debug more why the MysqliDb Class wasn't working correctly.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for your help. Hopefully something will turn up. I'm going to keep looking online too like you mentioned. Just wanted to turn here since I've had great success in the past.

Comment: You're welcome. Wish I could have been of more help. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something I'm missing why it will not work in mysqli?

No.
Both mysql and mysqli APIs run your queries exactly the same way.

Look for the typos. And other errors of the kind.